# Set calculation going wrong

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am doing something wrong but I don't know what, it is really annoying. I have the set (1,3,5,8 intersect 2,3,4,6) - (3,5,7 union 1,3,5,8) and I am getting the result 1,3,5,8,7 but in the answers it is stated that the set is {}. How can that be? Where am I doing the wrong thing?

Could you give me some tips when I it comes to simple set calculations?

I have edited the set since I messed up, now take a look at it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You should have that $$\{1,3,5,7\}\cap\{1,2,3\}=\{1,3\}.$$

By definition, $\bigl(\{1,3,5,7\}\cap\{1,2,3\}\bigr)\setminus\bigl(\{3,5,7\}\cup\{1,3,5,8\}\bigr)$ is the set of elements of $\{1,3,5,7\}\cap\{1,2,3\}$ that are *not* in $\{3,5,7\}\cup\{1,3,5,8\},$ so the desired set will have *at most* $1$ and $3$ as elements. Find $\{3,5,7\}\cup\{1,3,5,8\},$ then remove any elements of $\{1,3\}$ in this union, and you'll have the desired set.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what did you do wrong, when you didn't write how you got to your solution. Here is mine:

\begin{align*}
&A := \{1,3,5,8\} \cap \{1,2,3\} = \{1,3\}, \\
&B := \{3,5,7\} \cup \{1,3,5,8\} = \{1,3,5,7,8\}, \\
&A \setminus B = \emptyset.
\end{align*}

If you just noticed that you're removing $something \cup \{1,3,5,8\} \supseteq \{1,3,5,8\}$ from $something \cap \{1,3,5,8\} \subseteq \{1,3,5,8\}$, it should've been obvious that the solution is an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Let A={1,3,5,8}; B={1,2,3}, C={1,3,5,7} which is the union of the two sets that you said.

A$\cap$ B={1,3}. {1,3}-{1,3,5,7}={}, All the memember of {1,3} are in C, then {1,3} $\cap C^{c}$={}

The difference of two sets $A-B$, is the set of all memembers in A that are not in B.